# Replacing a number by character with apply depending of the data-frame row

Tags: r, replace, apply, gsub

I would like to replace a string (number '2' in my example) in a data-frame differently based on the row number. This is my input:

```
df <- "2 2 2 3
       3 3 2 1"
df <- read.table(text=df)
```

This would be my expected output:

```
dfout <- "1R 1R 1R 3
       3 3 2R 1"
dfout <- read.table(text=df)
```

Therefore, the number '2' should be replace by '1R' in the first row, by '2R' in the second row and so on in larger matrices (my real data has more than 1000 rows). I tried the below code without success:

```
apply(g1x, 1, function(x) gsub("2", nrow(x), x))
```

I would be glad for any help here.

Comment: In my example I have two rows, for the first row I would like to replace '2' by '1R', in the second row replace '2' by '2R' and so on. I updated my question for clarity.

Comment: @Sotos - of course `gsub` will accept functions if they give the right value - `apply(df, 1, function(x) gsub("2", length(x), x) )` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail, I thought they had to use `gsubfn` for that (thought that was its purpose). Maybe I rushed...

Answer (score 4):

A variation on @sotos' answer:

```
replace(df, df==2, paste0(row(df)[df==2], "R") 

#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1 1R 1R 1R  3
#2  3  3 2R  1
```

Equivalent to the replacement form of:

```
df[df==2] <- paste0(row(df)[df==2], "R")
```

Comment: Nice! Did not know about `row`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using `sapply` from base R,

```
 as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) 
                                       replace(df[i,], df[i,] == 2, paste0(i, 'R')))))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   V1 V2 V3 V4
> 1 1R 1R 1R  3
> 2  3  3 2R  1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is as base R method using `which`with the arr.ind argument. It is similar in spirit to thelatemail's method.

```
pos <- which(df == 2, arr.ind=TRUE)
df[pos] <- paste0(pos[,1], "R")
```

this returns

```
df
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 1R 1R 1R  3
2  3  3 2R  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

df <- "2 2 2 3
       3 3 2 1"
df <- data.table(read.table(text=df))

mycols <- names(df)
df[, (mycols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x==2, paste0(df[,.I], "R"),x)), .SDcols = mycols]
```